# Behavior for $orderby and $maxScan query modifiers vs sort() and limit() shell methods

Tags: mongodb, shell

I have a MongoDB collection that contains the following:

```
> db.foo.find()

{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "alpha", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:51.111Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "bravo", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:52.222Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "charlie", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:53.333Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "delta", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:54.444Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "echo", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:55.555Z") }
```

Here are the results for using shell methods:

```
> db.foo.find().sort({stamp:-1}).limit(3)

{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "echo", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:55.555Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "delta", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:54.444Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "charlie", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:53.333Z") }
```

Here are the results for using query modifiers:

```
> db.foo.find({$query:{},$orderby:{stamp:-1},$maxScan:3})

{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "charlie", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:53.333Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "bravo", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:52.222Z") }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "alpha", "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:51.111Z") }
```

It looks like the latter is applying the limit and then the orderby clause, which is not what I want. How do I get the query using modifiers to behave like the one using shell methods?

I'm trying to perform paging with a range query, using a web service that accepts a query string.  So I figure query modifiers are the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The `$maxScan` query modifier is not equivalent to a cursor limit.

The purpose of the `$maxScan` query modifier is to constrain potentially long running queries that may need to scan through a large number of documents to return the requested result.  You can make these queries more efficient by adding appropriate indexes so MongoDB can use the index instead of fetching documents to compare values.

For general queries and pagination you should be using [cursor methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/), including `limit()` and `skip()`.  These are methods on the result set cursor, not query modifiers.

#### Why are the results different?

The [`$maxScan`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxScan/) query modifier limits the number of documents that will be *scanned* when the query is processed.  This is different from the [cursor limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit) which affects the number of documents that will be *returned*.

> db.foo.find({$query:{},$orderby:{stamp:-1},$maxScan:3})

Since you do not have an index on `stamp` but are using this as a sort criteria, the outcome is that MongoDB will use the `_id` index to find all documents and then sort the results.  The `_id` index can't be used for comparing the `stamp` values, so the documents will have to be "scanned" by the query matcher. Including the `$maxScan` query modifier means that only the first 3 documents scanned will be used for the result set.

If you add an index to match your sort criteria, you would see the expected results:

```
> db.foo.ensureIndex({stamp:-1})

> db.foo.find({$query:{},$orderby:{stamp:-1},$maxScan:3})
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "name" : "echo",
    "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:55.555Z")
}
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "name" : "delta",
    "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:54.444Z")
}
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "name" : "charlie",
    "stamp" : ISODate("2013-06-13T12:12:53.333Z")
}
```

Comment: Using `cursor` methods would be preferable, but in this case I'm connecting to an existing web service from the client, so I'm stuck with query modifiers. [This document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-modifier/) led me to think `$maxScan` is the same as `limit()`. Your excellent explanation really clears things up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ytran:Thanks, that description in the manual is indeed misleading. I will submit a docs suggestion with a better explanation :).